# Javascript width of span element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create via a String some DOM-Elements and assign it via innerHTML to a div.
Now I need a flexible width of the span element (span_homebase). What I experience is that sometimes (for me it looks randomly) it returns other width than expected. I need the width of this span element because after this in the same line there is an Information Button but the width of the span could be different. So I use the width of span element as margin for the information button. Code is as follows. I searched for a async handler of innerHTML but in another post somebody said that it is not required because it is assigned instantly.
Are there any thoughts what to try? Because the information is now sometimes on the right place and sometimes not.

```
string = string + "<span id ='span_homebase'>" + homebaseCity + "</span>";
string = string + "<div class='section-end'></div>";
element.innerHTML = string;
var marginInfoHomebase = document.getElementById('span_homebase').offsetWidth + 20;
document.getElementById("information_button_homebase").style.margin = "5px 0 0 " + marginInfoHomebase + "px";
```

Now if I open the respective site for me sometimes the marginInfoHomebase sometimes returns 108 and sometimes 183 even if the same value is assigned to span element. Very strange. Any thoughts?

EDIT:
Working Example:

```
function createHomeSettingsView(settingsA){
    var element = document.getElementById("table-settings");
    var string = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < settingsA.length; i++){
        for(var z = 0; z < settingsA[i].length; z++){
            if(i == 1){
                //Notification buttons
                if(z == 1){
                    //homebase setting
                    if(window.localStorage.getItem("switch_homebase") == 1){
                        //homebase on
                        var homebaseCity = settingsA[i][z] + ": " + window.localStorage.getItem("homebase_loc");
                        string = string + " \
                        <div class='row' style='height:100px;' id='settings-sec-"+ i +"-row-" + z +"'> \
                            <div class='text'> \
                                <span id='span_homebase'>" + homebaseCity + "</span> \
                            </div> \
                            <div onClick='homebaseInfoClick();' class='information_button' id='information_button_homebase'></div>\
                            <div id='handleAutoSwitcherHomebase'></div>\
                            <div id='showRadiusRangeHomebase'>Radius: 30km</div>\
                            <input class='sliders' id='changeRadiusRangeHomebase' type='range' min='5' max='100' step='5' oninput='handleChangeHomebase(this.value)' onchange='handleInputHomebase(this.value)' >\
                        </div>";
                    }
                    else{
                        //homebase off
                        string = string + " \
                        <div class='row' id='settings-sec-"+ i +"-row-" + z +"'> \
                            <div class='text'>\
                                <span id='span_homebase'>" + settingsA[i][z] + "</span> \
                            </div> \
                            <div onClick='homebaseInfoClick();' class='information_button' id='information_button_homebase'></div>\
                            <div id='handleAutoSwitcherHomebase'></div>\
                        </div>";
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    }
    element.innerHTML = string;
    var marginInfoHomebase = document.getElementById("span_homebase").offsetWidth + 25;
    var marginText = "5px 0 0 " + marginInfoHomebase + "px";
    console.log("Span: " + marginInfoHomebase);
    document.getElementById("information_button_homebase").style.margin = marginText;
}
```

CSS:

```
.container .table-settings{
    top: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    background-color: #ECEBF3;
}

.container .table-settings .row{
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 14px;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid LightGray;
}

.container .table-settings .row .text{
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: black;
    float: left;
}

#span_homebase{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default a **span** element has no dimension because its CSS **display** property is **inline**.

If you want to give it a width, you should change that property to **inline-block**.

```
<style>
span {
    display: inline-block ;
}
</style>
```

Now you can play with its dimensions.

Comment: thats what I also currently discovered. Thanks :)!! Now it works everytime. But was strange that sometimes it was correct and sometimes not

Comment: actually the dimension properties still exist for an `inline` element but they are dynamically calculated (based on content and on the surrounding `block` and `inline-block` elements). So they could be correct sometimes I guess.

Comment: I added this and worked. But now sometimes I discover that it is possible that there are three different values returned. How could that be? Really I don't know why. I thought this is fixed now but sometimes it happens that it returns 184 or 208 but should be 224. Any thoughts?

Comment: The browser try to use the defined value if possible otherwise it will estimate a value depending on the available layout. You should post a running example if you need more explanation.

Comment: I added my respective Code is this enough?

Comment: @Moritz Thank you but could you give a *live* example? There's a button on the edition UI where you can add some JS / HTML / CSS files.

Comment: Thx, too hard at the moment to extract the exact minimal things I need for a working example, sorry :-/. I think at the moment I'll fix it with a workaround and show the information button simply before the text. But if you want to check the Bug live in app download this: www.meetfriends.me/getapp.html and go to settings and activate homebase ;) pretty ugly sometimes, isn't it :D

Answer (score 19):

To get an inline element's width use getBoundingClientRect method:

```
var mySpan = document.getElementById("mySpan");

var spanWidth = mySpan.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var spanHeight = mySpan.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```